# Jquery .on('click') not working within refreshing div

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(refreshDiv, 500); 
});
function refreshDiv(){
    $('#a').html('<p><span>user1</span> - <a href="#">room</a></p>');
}
$(function() {  
    $('#a p span').on('click',function(e){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
</script>
<body><div id="a"></div></body>
```

I wanna click on span and get it's value. But it's not working.
Any ideas to fix this please??
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to use event delegation:

```
$("#a").on("click", "span", function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

I notice you also have two elements with the ID of `a` -- remember, ID's **must** be unique!

Comment: Thank you soo much.. 
Duplicated ID was a mistake. I fixed it.